# My AVD creator window is missing setting RAM option

Tags: android, ram, android-virtual-device, windows-xp-sp2

I am new to Android.I have made a HelloWorld application and want to run it in Android emulator.But the emulator is not showing anything apart from the text 'Android'. I later come to know that my AVD creator window is incomplete.It is missing the setting memory option for RAM and SD card. Now, I have only 1 GB RAM and running XP SP2, so how I can get a proper window to create AVD?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution myself.I did not install anything apart from Android Developer Tools such as Open GL ES, DDMS, I installed them via Help->Install New Software in Eclipse.Now I get the full window.