# HAXM Hardware Requirements

Tags: android, haxm

Do i need to upgrade my processor to run HAXM or have i missed something? If i have missed something, any hints would be greatly appreciated :)

1. My processor is Intel Core2 6300 @ 1.86GHz 1.86GHz installed memory 4.00 Gb. Running on Win7.
2. I have enabled VT in the BIOS, but it is for 16 and 32 bits? Is this a problem?
3. I have run the intel processor identification utility, file pidenu39.msi from ...
   [Intel® Processor Identification Utility - Windows* Version](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=7838)

   It tells me on the CPU Technologies tab that my processor **does** have Intel Virtualization Technology, but **does not** have VT-x Virtualization Technology with Extended Page Tables. Is this OK?
4. From this website , [Configuring Virtual Machine Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm)

i have followed all of the instructions under this heading ...
Configuring VM Acceleration on Windows

**sc query intel haxm** does indicate that the virtualization driver is operating correctly.

5. I am running the newest version of Android Studio. I am running the very simple Hello Android app from the Android Application Devekopment for Dummies book, chapter 3. Nothing complex or messy here :)

I get this message sequence ...

```
C:\AndroidSDK\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

emulator: device fd:584

```
**HAX is not working** and emulator runs in emulation mode

emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit
.
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
creating window 39 53 300 532
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156 error 0x501
```

Followed by many more error `0x501s`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix: "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode)

Comment: How much RAM is set for use inside your AVD configuration ? this number has to be lower or equal to the memory usage you have set during the installation of HAXM.

Comment: OK, i do not know how much RAM is assigned inside the AVD, and i do not see where to find or reset it? When i was using Eclipse/ADT it was right there in the VDM, but in this new IDE i do not see it?

Comment: when you create a new `AVD` you will be prompted for the RAM assignment.

Comment: I start AVD, Create VD, choose phone Nexus 5, choose Lollipop 21 x86 Google, click finish, next screen allows scale change but not asked about mem allocation? Thanx, Mick

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214724/my-avd-creator-window-is-missing-setting-ram-option

Comment: Thanks, but that member was using the Eclipse/ADT. There i can see and set all the VD options. In the new development environment i can set only the phone type and the API. I worked thru "everything" but i must be missing something. Mick

Comment: If I am not wrong you are using Android Studio, well..there is an option for RAM size when creating virtual device from AVD , please read this, http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html ..also the default ram size is `96 megabytes`

Comment: Sorry, i am not used to the structure of this forum yet, and it is quite different from the others that i use. It says that i do not have enough rep [or whatever] to move to chat.

Comment: @sufiyan, thank you very much. I reduced the memory requirement and got past that error. So to answer my original question, it seems that the hardware that i have, with just VT and not VT-x will be OK. Perhaps i should consider upgrading? Thanx again, Mick

Comment: your original question was to fix the error, if you want more memory then re-install HAXM with the size of RAM you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much RAM is set for use inside your AVD configuration ? this number has to be lower or equal to the memory usage you have set during the installation of HAXM.

If I am not wrong you are using `Android Studio`, and there is an option for RAM size when creating virtual device from `AVD` , please read this, [Managing AVDs with AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)

Also, the default ram size is `96 megabytes`.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, but if you want to change the amount of ram that HAXM has available you can re-run the installation and it will allow you to alter the setting.

I found this out by accident when I was trying to update HAXM. The last page of the install tells you that you can change the setting by re-running install.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a similar processor, core i3, in my VAIO laptop.  VT was also enabled on the BIOS and the problem was fixed when I uninstalled the avast anti-virus(no disabling the protection) and so I could finish the HAMX installation. After that, I installed the Avast software again.

I hope this issue can help more people.