# My emulator wont work and I keep getting these error messages

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have tried searching the forum for answers but cannot find anything to resolve my problem. These are the error messages I am getting when running my app in the emulator.

```
    WARNING: userdata image already in use, changes will not persist! 
WARNING: cache image already in use, changes will not persist! 
WARNING: SD Card image already in use: /Users/glenmcmurchy/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_22_x86.avd/sdcard.img 
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration. 
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode 
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode. emulator: 
emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

I got told to delete my emulator and reinstall it, would that work? however I cannot figure out how to delete/uninstall it :/

I have also tried increasing the memory but that doesnt seem to work either, either that or I have not done it properly.

Comment: I think you should visit HAXM Hardware Requirements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668832/haxm-hardware-requirements

Comment: Delete the *.lock dirs in your AVD directory it is on /android/adv/

Comment: Hi Skizo, I cannot find the *.lock dirs? where is adv? or do you mean /android/avd/ howver I still cannot find it there either